# D3Plus Visualization with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, d3plus

I'm trying to run the example from this [Link](http://d3plus.org/examples/advanced/9860411/), but the only thing I get is a grey box (nothing happens when I click it). I'm using the d3plus-react package, version 0.5.2 with react version 16.7.0. Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Treemap } from "d3plus-react";

const methods = {
data: [
    { value: 100, name: "alpha", group: "group 1" },
    { value: 70, name: "beta", group: "group 2" },
    { value: 40, name: "gamma", group: "group 2" },
    { value: 15, name: "delta", group: "group 2" },
    { value: 5, name: "epsilon", group: "group 1" },
    { value: 1, name: "zeta", group: "group 1" }
  ],
  id: ["group", "name"],
  size: "value"
};

class Hierarcy extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Treemap config={methods} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Hierarcy;
```

I would appreciate any help :)
ps: I forgot to mention that I created the app with create-react-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have to use `groupBy: ["group", "name"]` instead of `id`.

Unfortunately, the linked *Grouped TreeMap* visualization is from version 1.0 of d3Plus, you can see here the old examples including the mentioned https://d3plus.org/examples/1.0/. d3Plus-react uses version 2.0 of d3Plus and when using the Treemap component you are using [d3plus-hierarchy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/d3plus-hierarchy) and in this case a gruped visualization looks like this https://d3plus.org/examples/d3plus-hierarchy/getting-started/, without the interactivity you want on click.

To show the tooltip with the value in this version it's necessary to 
pass `tooltipConfig` configuration.

```
const methods = {
  groupBy: ["group", "name"],
  data: [
    { value: 100, name: "alpha", group: "group 1" },
    { value: 70, name: "beta", group: "group 2" },
    { value: 40, name: "gamma", group: "group 2" },
    { value: 15, name: "delta", group: "group 2" },
    { value: 5, name: "epsilon", group: "group 1" },
    { value: 1, name: "zeta", group: "group 1" }
  ],
  tooltipConfig: {
    body: d => `<div>Value: ${d.value}</div>`,
    title: d => `${d.name}`
  }
}
```

Comment: Now I can see the data, but I only see it in the two groups (group 1 and 2), but not with depth (not with grouping with "group" and "name"), like in the example. When I click still nothing happens, I can't even see the tooltip with the data, just with the names from "name".

Comment: I updated my answer, unfortunately, I can't find how to implement the click functionality in version 2.0 of d3Plus this behaviour seems to be available only on version 1.0.

Comment: Oh, I see. It´s a shame it doesn´t have the option to do that. Thanks anyway for your answer!